# Kivy - Adding widgets to a class

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I am trying to add a widget to a class but it is not working.
Example:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
<test>:
    Label:
        text: "Hi!"
''')
class test(GridLayout):
    def build(self):
         pass
testbutton=Button(text="This I want to show on test class!")
test().add_widget(testbutton)
class apprun(App):
    def build(self):
        return test()
apprun().run()
```

When run, this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally good practice to explain *how* things don't work. For instance, you might have a useful python traceback including information about an exception that was raised, or you might simply mean you don't get the result you expect in which case you should explain how.

In this case, the obvious problem is that you try to inherit from `app`, when you mean `App`. Since `app` doesn't exist this would throw an exception.

You also try to add a widget to a class definition (`test`) rather than an instance of a class (`test()`). This will also fail, and if you don't see why you should read about the difference between class definitions and instances.

Also, widgets don't need a `build` method, this will do nothing.

Comment: Sorry about the errors in the program, I just roughly typed it up as an example for here, but anyway without the errors, it just shows Hi! and not the Button, and I want to make the class while using the builder so I cant do a class definition.

Comment: That's because you add the widget to one instance of test, but then return a totally different one in the app's build method. Add the widget to the instance you return, each instance is separate.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were going for?

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<test>:
    Label:
        text: "Hi!"
''')

class test(GridLayout):
    pass

class apprun(App):
    def build(self):
        t = test()
        b = Button(text="This I want to show on test class!")
        t.add_widget(b)     
        return t

apprun().run()
```

Or maybe this... so your widgets don't overlap each other.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<test>:
    Label:
        text: "Hi!"
''')

class test(GridLayout):
    pass

class apprun(App):
    def build(self):
        t = test(cols=1, size=Window.size)
        b=Button(text="This I want to show on test class!")
        t.add_widget(b)     
        return t

apprun().run()
```